# nx.node_connectivity and nx.minimum_node_cut arent' matching up

Tags: python, networkx

This returns 1:

```
nx.node_connectivity(G_sc,97,38)
```

but,
`nx.minimum_node_cut(G_sc, 97, 38)` returns an empty list. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By checking on a sample graph, a possible explanation is likely to be as shown here. Take for instance:

```
G = nx.from_edgelist([[1,4], [1,3], [4,3], [4,5], [1,2], [2,5]])
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color='lightgreen')
```

[image]

If we take say, nodes `3` and `5`:

```
nx.node_connectivity(G,3,5) 
# 2
nx.minimum_node_cut(G, 3,5)
# {2, 4}
```

Everything seems as expected, since as mentioned in the docs in [`nx.minimum_node_cut`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/_modules/networkx/algorithms/connectivity/cuts.html#minimum_node_cut), this is a set of nodes of minimum cardinality that disconnects `G`.

Though if we try on `4` and `5` for instance:

```
nx.node_connectivity(G,4,5) 
# 2
nx.minimum_node_cut(G, 4,5)
#{}
```

We get an empty `set` as a result of `nx.minimum_node_cut`, even though it is clear that we'd need to remove two paths to disconnect them, as specified by `nx.node_connectivity`.

The explanation seems to be that in the case where both `source` and `target` nodes specified in `nx.minimum_node_cut` are adjacent, the returned subset does not consider any other paths, since the solution excludes the trivial answer of removing the edge connecting both adjacent nodes.
So it is likely that this is what is happening in your actual case.